# How to test Polymer dom attribute?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a test suite like this:

```
setup(function() {
  form = fixture('basic');
});

test('hide and show error message', function() {
  title = Polymer.dom(form.root).querySelector('#title');
  save = Polymer.dom(form.root).querySelector('#save');

  expect(Polymer.dom(title).hasAttribute('invalid')).to.be.false;
  MockInteractions.tap(save);
  expect(Polymer.dom(title).hasAttribute('invalid')).to.be.true;
});
```

And of course, `Polymer.dom(...)` doesn't have function `hasAttribute()`

How can I get the attribute to compare, or is there another way to test the `invalid` attribute of `paper-input`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
expect(title.inputElement.invalid).to.be.false;
```